# Get error: BodyMassApplet is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent)

Tags: java, abstraction

I keep getting this error and I cant seem to figure out why any ideas?(wont compile)
This is a applet built from my working console app (educational reasons).
Thanks guys...

error: BodyMassApplet is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
    public class BodyMassApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener

code:

```
/*
        Name : ****************
        Date : 13/02/14
        Reason : Bodymass calculator
        Chapter : 3
        Programs Name : BodyMassApplet.java

*/

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BodyMassApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
        //declare vars
        Image logo;//declare an image object
        int inches, pounds;
        double meters, kilograms, index;

        //construct components
        Label companyLabel = new Label ("THE SUN FITNESS CENTER BODY MASS INDEX CALCULATOR");
        Label heightLabel = new  Label("Enter your height to the nearest inch : ");
            TextField heightFeild = new TextField (10);
        Label weightLabel = new Label ("Enter your weight to the nearest pound : ");
            TextField weightFeild = new TextField (10);
        Button calcButton = new Button ("Calculate");
        Label outputLabel = new Label ("Click the Calculate button to see your Body Mass Index. ");

        public void init()
        {
            setForeground(Color.red);
            add(companyLabel);
            add(heightLabel);
            add(heightFeild );
            add(weightLabel);
            add(weightFeild);
            add(calcButton);
            calcButton.addActionListener(this);
            add(outputLabel);
            logo = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"log.gif");
        }//Close init method


        public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            inches = Integer.parseInt(heightFeild.getText());
            pounds = Integer.parseInt(weightFeild.getText());
            meters = inches /39.36;
            kilograms =pounds /2.2;
            index = kilograms / Math.pow(meters,2);
            outputLabel.setText("Your Body Mass Index Is" + Math.round(index)+ ".");
        }


        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawImage(logo,125,160,this);
        }







}//close applet class
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a typo, you wrote

```
public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e)
```

but you meant:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
```

I recommend to use an IDE like Eclipse which would have pointed out that problem to you.

Comment: Don't answer questions, that are off-topic in Programmers. Don' create more mess. Flag as off-topic and advice (in comment) OP to ask at Stack Overflow, as just gnat did.

Comment: Thanks guys, I found it a few min after asking the question but don't have enough point to answer my own question...Yeah i know about eclipse although the course im doing comes with soft ware we have to use its a introduction to java course so i have to use a basic editor cant use a IDE....might sound odd, but how is it off topic this is the java exchange?